# java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection while connecting to database

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, primavera

When I am trying to connect to the Dev database(which is installed in other server) from our Dev application server using the JDBC connection I am getting the below error(not able to connect from SQL Developer also)

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at oraclejdbc.OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:60)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:359)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:333)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:141)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:337)
    ... 12 more
```

From the same application Dev server we are able to connect to other databases and from the other servers and systems I am able to connect to Dev database.
I am facing the issue when connecting to Dev database only from Dev server.

We had checked ping,telnet and traceroute for the dev database server and all are working fine.

Comment: Also we have added the entry in hosts file from application server side.

Comment: Also I am using the correct port and correct host name, any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Any one has faced this issue before?